# Java enum confusion with creating a bitmask and checking permissions

Tags: java, permissions, bit-manipulation

I want to port this c# permission module to java, but I am confused how I can do this when I can't save the numeric value in the database and then cast it to the enumeration representation.

In c#, I create a enum like this:

```
public enum ArticlePermission
{
     CanRead   = 1,
     CanWrite  = 2,
     CanDelete = 4,
     CanMove   = 16
}
```

I then can create a permission set like:

```
ArticlePermission johnsArticlePermission = ArticlePermission.CanRead | ArticlePermission.CanMove;
```

I then save this into the database using:

```
(int)johnsArticlePermission
```

Now I can read it from the database as an integer/long, and cast it like:

```
johnsArticlePermission = (ArticlePermission) dr["articlePermissions"];
```

And I can check permissions like:

```
if(johnsArticlePermission & ArticlePermission.CanRead == ArticlePermission.CanRead) 
{

}
```

How can I do this in java?
From what I understand, in java, you can convert the enumeration into a numeric value, and then convert it back to a java enumeration.

Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067352/can-set-enum-start-value-in-java

Comment: [And this, which directly addressing storing enums to the DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229856/ways-to-save-enums-in-database).

Comment: @DaveNewton if I use an enumset, I can't save it the same way since getting the name won't make sense if I have OR'd 3 enum values no?

Comment: [And this, which directly addresses storing `EnumSets` to a DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199399/storing-enumset-in-a-database).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you really need here is an [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html), described in the API like this:

> Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This
>   representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time
>   performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a
>   high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit
>   flags."

An enum is a class under the hood so you can add methods to it.  For example,

```
public enum ArticlePermission
{
  CanRead(1),
  CanWrite(2),
  CanDelete(4),
  CanMove(16); // what happened to 8?

  private int _val;
  ArticlePermission(int val)
  {
    _val = val;
  }

  public int getValue()
  {
    return _val;
  }

  public static List<ArticlePermission> parseArticlePermissions(int val)
  {
    List<ArticlePermission> apList = new ArrayList<ArticlePermission>();
    for (ArticlePermission ap : values())
    {
      if (val & ap.getValue() != 0)
        apList.add(ap);
    }
    return apList;
  }
}
```

`parseArticlePermissions` will give you a `List` of `ArticlePermission` objects from an integer value, presumably created by ORing the value of `ArticlePermission` objects.

Here is a more detailed [explanation of EnumSet](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enumset).

Comment: where did `values()` come from?

Comment: @Blankman `values()` is a [feature of enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: If doing Android, please avoid EnumSets these are very inefficient for the DalvikVM.

Comment: Has this changed for ART?

Comment: Both blog links are broken now (but the documentation link still works).

Comment: @Dov Thank you, I updated the answer with a link to the current Java API and a working link to another article on `EnumSet`.