# Is it a good way to implement Distance with diffrent units

Tags: java, design-patterns, distance

I was looking for some good patterns to have possibility to express distance in different units. I found [Martin Fowler article about quantities](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) and I programmed something like:

Here is Distance class ( I think it is not necessery to make it abstract ):

```
public class Distance {
    double mValue;
    DistanceUnit mUnit;

    public Distance(double value, DistanceUnit unit){
        this.mValue = value;
        this.mUnit = unit;
    }

    public Distance toUnit(DistanceUnit unit){
        double factor = this.mUnit.getMetresFactor()/unit.getMetresFactor();
        double newValue = this.mValue * factor;
        Distance distance = new Distance(newValue, unit);
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(mValue);
    }
}
```

It looks very simple. Conversion `toUnit` is based on `DistanceUnit` method `getMetresFactor`. Each Unit class implements `DistanceUnit` interface and has method `getMetresFactor()` like:

```
public interface DistanceUnit {
    double getMetresFactor();
}


public class Inch implements DistanceUnit {
    @Override
    public double getMetresFactor() {
        return 0.0254;
    }
}


public class Kilometer implements DistanceUnit {
    @Override
    public double getMetresFactor() {
        return 1000.0;
    }
}
```

And the usage is for example:

```
Distance inches = new Distance(300.0, new Inch());
Distance kilometres = inches.toUnit(new Kilometres());
```

So it returns the correct value.

Is it good way to store distance in this way? Maybe you know some weaknesses of this approach. Maybe is a good idea to use here a FactoryMethod pattern to construct distance based on unit shortcut like "m" for meter. I think about the amount of classes if I would have a lot of units... Is it good idea to have factory which return factor of meters based on unit name? There will be no classes for units then?

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, have you thought about using a library like [JScience](http://jscience.org/) which already exists?

Comment: I was expecting that somewhere is somethin like JScience but I haven't heard about it I haven't found it. I will check it out. But my question was also if it is a good way to do that like I did. I'm not very experienced programmer so each good word form me is worth much.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen 
like that he can use his own distances. There is no problem to reinvent the wheel if it is simpler and faster as use an existed bad one

Answer (score 2):

Hm, i would use enum instead of DistanceUnit classes, because there is no different instances of them.
You can set a value to enum [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067352/can-set-enum-start-value-in-java)

and then call enum.getValue() instead of unit.getMetresFactor().
Also it is a little bit confusing, is the mValue value in meters or in DistanceUnit's, if in meters, you must have

```
double factor =  unit.getMetresFactor();
```

there
Ok and now with any convertion function support:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public abstract class MeasureConverter {

public abstract double valueToBasic(double value);

public abstract double basictoValue(double basic);

/**
 *
 */
public static Map<String, MeasureConverter> converters;

public static Map<String, MeasureConverter> getConverters() {
    if (converters == null) {
        converters = new HashMap<String, MeasureConverter>();

        converters.put("kilo", new MeasureConverter() {

            @Override
            public double valueToBasic(double value) {
                return value * 1000;
            }

            @Override
            public double basictoValue(double basic) {
                return basic / 0.001;
            }
        });

        // taking the basic temperature value in kelvines
        converters.put("kelvine", new MeasureConverter() {

            @Override
            public double valueToBasic(double value) {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public double basictoValue(double basic) {
                return basic;
            }
        });

        converters.put("celsius", new MeasureConverter() {

            @Override
            public double valueToBasic(double value) {
                return value + 273.15;
            }

            @Override
            public double basictoValue(double basic) {
                return basic - 273.15;
            }
        });

        converters.put("faren", new MeasureConverter() {

            @Override
            public double valueToBasic(double value) {
                return value * 1.8 - 459.67 ; // or whatever is there?
            }

            @Override
            public double basictoValue(double basic) {
                return (basic + 459.67  ) / 1.8;// or whatever is there?
            }
        });

    }

    return converters;
}
```

}

And then :

```
import java.util.Objects;


public class MeasurePattern {

double value;
String name;

public MeasurePattern(double value, String name) {
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MeasurePattern{" + "value=" + value + ", name=" + name + '}';
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 29 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.value) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.value) >>> 32));
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final MeasurePattern other = (MeasurePattern) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.value) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.value)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public MeasurePattern convertTo(String converter) {

    MeasureConverter mycon = MeasureConverter.getConverters().get(name);
    MeasureConverter hiscon = MeasureConverter.getConverters().get(converter);

    double basic = mycon.valueToBasic(value);
    double hisValue = hiscon.basictoValue(basic);
    return new MeasurePattern(hisValue, converter);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //trying temperatures;

    MeasurePattern temp = new MeasurePattern(10, "celsius");

    MeasurePattern kelvine = temp.convertTo("kelvine");
    MeasurePattern faren = kelvine.convertTo("faren");
    MeasurePattern cels = faren.convertTo("celsius");

    System.out.println("kelvine = " + kelvine);
    System.out.println("faren = " + faren);
    System.out.println("cels = " + cels);

}
```

}

Output:

```
kelvine = MeasurePattern{value=283.15, name=kelvine}
faren = MeasurePattern{value=412.67777777777775, name=faren}
cels = MeasurePattern{value=9.999999999999943, name=celsius}
```

Comment: but if somebody wanted to add new unit he would have to edit the enum class? So I would need to add all possible units to enum ?

Comment: Yes i think its not so wrong with editing an enum. In the practical world.
If you realy want no modifications...

Ahh, you can create a **map** of distance unit valies like
HashMap<String,Double> dims; where you put like
dims.put("kilometer", 0.001);
dims.put("inch", <whatever);
then somebody would need just to add a new entry to the map, it is better then create a new almost empty class.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I see. I still think about the lib that Tim Biegeleisen showed. Isn't it better to use it instead of rewriting it? It really so slow lib?

Comment: @ Patryk Imosa
my point is if you have a simple task just use your own classes, of course good written, later gather your own util's lib where you know everything, else you must spend lot of time to learn the foreign lib, and it's documented and **non-documented** behavior :D

Comment: I think I would avoid the factor altogether. With temperature conversion (eg. F to C) you'll have to add the base offset as well (32). Maybe other systems have a non-linear factor or another piece of information is required.

Comment: @Caramiriel you mean if I did more general class such as Measure ? Then I would have to have some other methods for cases? When I extend it like Distance, Speed, Temperature?

Comment: @PatrykImosa I think each concept itself needs a class (`Distance`/`Velocity`) and stick to a base unit (`Distance` in meters, `Velocity` in meter/second). Upon outputting (for the user), determine how to format it. Eg. https://gist.github.com/Feanathiel/fdc188ada35b8da44dfe07f98494c0ba

Comment: If I wanted to add new unit I need to edit this class...I thought about something complex

Comment: ok, @Patryk Imosa i ll edit my comment (see above) to show my fast- made variabt with any function, mentioned by  Caramiriel with example of temperature measures

Comment: Look at my code I also do it this way...For example Distance main unit is meter "m", so each implementation of DistanceUnit interface has getMeterFactor() for example 1 km is 1000m. Then in distance in `toUnit` function I firstly convert my value to meters and then I convert it by dividing to chosen unit that has meter factor. For instance 1km i convert to m by mul by 1000 (in km class m factor is 1000) and I have meters and then to inchs by dividing 1000 by 0.0254 (its inchs factor)

Comment: @JJ Maybe _you_ know everything in your libs (whereas also your own libs will definitively have non-intended behaviour), but what if someone else has to work with your code? Open-source libraries may be already known, better documented, better tested and quicker fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it analog to `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` as an enum. E.g.

```
public enum DistanceUnit {

  KILOMETER {
    @Override
    protected double conversionFactor(DistanceUnit toDistanceUnit) {
      switch (toDistanceUnit) {
        case KILOMETER:
          return 1;
        case MILE:
          return 0.621371;
        default:
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(toDistanceUnit + " is not supported");
      }
    }
  },

  MILE {
    @Override
    protected double conversionFactor(DistanceUnit toDistanceUnit) {
      switch (toDistanceUnit) {
        case KILOMETER:
          return 1.60934;
        case MILE:
          return 1;
        default:
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(toDistanceUnit + " is not supported");
      }
    }
  };

  public double toDistance(double value, DistanceUnit targetDistance) {
    return value * conversionFactor(targetDistance);
  }

  protected abstract double conversionFactor(DistanceUnit toDistanceUnit);

}
```

change your `Distance` class to

```
public class Distance {
    double mValue;
    DistanceUnit mUnit;

    public Distance(double value, DistanceUnit unit){
        this.mValue = value;
        this.mUnit = unit;
    }

    public Distance toUnit(DistanceUnit unit){
        double newValue = mUnit.toDistance(mValue, unit);
        Distance distance = new Distance(newValue, unit);
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(mValue);
        }
}
```

and the client code will look very clear

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Distance kilometers = new Distance(265.35, DistanceUnit.KILOMETER);
    Distance miles = kilometers.toUnit(DistanceUnit.MILE);
    System.out.println(miles);
  }
}
```

will output

```
164.88079485000003
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "Strategy" pattern.

An interface:

```
 public interface DistanceUnit {
     double getDistance(int metres);
 }
```

The Inch class:

```
public class Inch implements DistanceUnit {
    @Override
    public double getDistance(int metres) {
       return meters*39; //do conversion here
    }
}
```

The Kilometers class:

```
public class Kilometres implements DistanceUnit {
    @Override
    public double getDistance(int metres) {
        return meters/1000; //do conversion here
    }
}
```

Then:

```
List<DistanceUnit> distanceList = new ArrayList<>();
distanceList.add(new Inch());
distanceList.add(new Kilometres());


for (DistanceUnit item : distanceList) {
    System.out.println(item.getDistance(1000));
}
```

If I understand you, I think it is a simple and clean solution.

You can follow this model for conversion between others units.

Comment: I don't think so it is a good solution. If I wanted to convert kilometers to inchs ? So it is not automated.

Comment: You can have different hierarchies and maintain them independently. I think it's always better to make more classes and write less code.

Comment: PS: If a new unit distance is invented in the future you must add  only your new conversion hierarchy. Decouple is good.

Answer (score 0):

Java convention does not use a m(ember) prefix (but say a `this.` qualification), and convention is taken quite seriously in java (as opposed to C++ for instance).

toString misses the unit.

JScience offers more, the capability to calculate in different units, `m/s²`, and so on. Your class is a nice abstraction. But in a wider context, you probably will want to have math operations, powers of units (-2 for `s` above).

Take a look at your own usage ideas first:

(Just garbage:)

```
U speedUnit = U.of(Distance::km, Time::h.up(-1));
double timeInS = U.mile(40).div(speedunit(30)).in(U.m);
```

Comment: Yes, I see, I did it because I was just a little bit confused when I was multiplying them. So I see that in my problem I would need to program a lot that is already implemented.

Comment: Otherwise it would not be very interesting? Maybe play a bit with the JScience examples, and look whether you can make it better. They have _aliases_ (if I remember correctly) like Hz for s-1 and such.